# VS crashes and winforms data lost

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I am developing an application using Visual Studio 2019 and I am designing winforms.
Visual Studio commonly crashes when I am creating the forms by freezing, and recently my designed winform has somehow disappeared (even though I saved it). When i open it it shows as the default winform that is shown when a new one is created:[image: My VS winform has somehow been corrupted and lost all data.]

When I browse the solution explorer it seems that I can still see all the components I had added to the form:[image: Solution explorer shows my missing components.]

Finally, when I try to restart and manually add the components back, I get an error message saying that the component can't be added due to duplication - which is probably because they are somehow still there (as shown in the solution explorer) but the data has been corrupted somehow:
[image: Error message when trying to add the components back]

If anybody has any idea of how to recover the data and the winform, I would very much appreciate it. If any additional information is required, please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

According to your description, first, the controls actually exist, but they are not

displayed in the design window.

You can try to check whether the. add statement of each control added to the window still

exists in the .Design.cs file.

If not, you can add it manually.

Second, solution explorer shows the missing components, but there is an error in adding

components. It means that only the declaration of this control in the .Design.cs file does

not assign a value to this control. You can delete the declaration of the component in the

.Design.cs file, and then add the component in the design interface.

Result:

[image]

[image]